# How can I register null value in unity registration inside my unity config xml file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inversion-of-control, config, app-config

I have a situation where when I request a particular type to my unity container, it should return "null" value.

Something like

```
<register type="MyNamespace.MyType" mapTo="null" />
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: This question feels incomplete or maybe it is just me. Can you describe what you trying to do? Give an example....

Comment: Basically, I do not want unity to throw any exception when type of MyNamespace.MyType is requested. I just want a null value to be returned instead.